# Obsolete reports error while deploying components through SVN

Tags: reporting, deployment

I'm getting an error that 'Salesforce report is obsolete' while trying to deploy reports through svn. I searched for resolving this error on google and found that this happens because 'Enable reports' permission is not enabled for the related object in the target org. So, for the particular object I made the  tag true in the object file and then checked in both the report and object file but still I'm getting the same error. 
Any idea as to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

After creation of report, if you change the data model (From Lookup to Master-detail or vice-versa), you will also get this error.

Thanks,
Leanas Nixon.

Comment: This also occurs if you are using an External Datasource and it becomes invalid (e.g. based on custom Apex class that is no longer compiling).